# If I std::dynamic_pointer_cast and the result of the underlying dynamic_cast is null, is the returned shared_ptr guaranteed to store null inside?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Why I am a bit confused about this:

std::shared_ptr can be *empty* and std::shared_ptr can point to null and these two concepts are not equivalent.

an empty shared_ptr can store a non-null value and a shared_ptr that stores null can have a positive ref-count.

What I wonder now is how do I properly test after a std::dynamic_pointer_cast whether the cast was successful or not? the docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast state:

```
3-4) dynamic_cast<Y*>(r.get()) (If the result of the dynamic_cast is a null pointer value, the returned shared_ptr will be empty.)
```

but since an *empty* shared_ptr isn't guaranteed to store a null value, I'm not sure what's the proper well-defined test for whether the dynamic cast succeeded

Comment: `empty shared_ptr isn't guaranteed to store a null value` well, but if it doesn't point to null, then it should point to a valid object, and that object will be then `dynamic_cast<Y*>`. `whether the cast was successful or not? ` it's `try { ... } catch(std::bad_cast)`

Comment: @KamilCuk dynamic_pointer_cast does not throw exceptions. where is it guaranteed to point to a valid object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not super sure, but here goes:

[The c++17 and c++20 standard drafts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links) declare in (23.11.2.2.9 shared_ptr casts)

`shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<U>& r) noexcept;`

Returns:

(5.1) — When `dynamic_cast<typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get())` returns a nonzero
value `p`, `shared_ptr<T>(r, p)`

Otherwise, `shared_ptr<T>()`.

The default constructor of `shared_ptr<T>`, defined in (20.11.3.11 Constructors)
has as post condition

`use_count() == 0 && get() == nullptr`

I read that as: if the raw pointer cast returns `nullptr`, the smart pointer cast will hold a `nullptr`.

Therefore I think that a dynamic_pointer_cast is successful, if the resulting shared pointer does not hold a null pointer (it might also hold a null pointer when successful but that is --up to now-- of no relevance in my applications).

But I must say that this was my first venture into the c++ standard and I, too, don't understand, how a failed dynamic cast could ever hold a non-null empty pointer, although I have also read that.